# Seahorse sometimes doesn't show passwords section

Tags: google-chrome, password, seahorse

This is driving me crazy. Occasionally when I start Chrome after a reboot, it does not show up on my screen. The process is running, but no window is opened. After a lot of digging around, it looks like the problem is that it is waiting for some authorization for accessing the password storage.

When Chrome works, I can see a section titled "Passwords" on the left side of the "Password and Keys" (AKA Seahorse) app. When the problem occurs, that section is not there. The Certificates, Secure Shell and PGP Keys sections are there, but the Passwords section is not.

[image: seahorse window]

I looked through all the menu options and I was not able to get it to re-appear. After restarting, it sometimes comes back, and sometimes not.

Any idea what is going on, and how I can make the Passwords section appear when it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be security/login-related. Are any online accounts accessed in Chrome entered in Settings | Online Accounts? If they are, an *Unlock Login Keyring* dialog should greet you immediately upon login after a reboot. Type in your password (or have xdotool do it for you) and everything remains secure, no more troubles (normally).

Too late to make a difference for OP, but maybe help others.

Comment: Not too late, actually. Where is "Settings | Online Accounts"? In Chrome? In Seahorse? Is there a way to force the *Unlock Login Keyring* dialog to show?

Comment: Took for granted a reinstall would've happened a short time after your post. Settings is 'System Settings'. If running the default interface, click Activities at upper left and key "onl" in search; Online Accounts shortcut should pop up to click. Add the account (typically Google), that's all. Forever more, the dialog should be triggered on each login. Please post your results.